# what should an invitation letter from UK look like ? , how to approve it legally?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, lebanese-citizens

I'm new to the community, my friend moved to the UK, Leicester city,
I want to visit her, as I asked before if I can convince the council that my circumstances in my home country is good the application may be accepted.

Anyway a letter from her may support my application more, I want to know what should this invitation letter form look like, and how can I show it to the council and approve that it's not fake, and legally approved ??

I'd be grateful for any help.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 3):

UKVI approves visa applications, not ‘the council’. The invitation letter from your friend is just a personal letter from them addressed to you; it cannot be ‘legally approved’.  It should include the dates during which you are invited to visit, a brief reason for the invitation, and a statement about where you will stay / support being provided by your friend (if relevant). As stated in the answer to your first question [Can I get a visitor VISA invitation from a non UK student living in the uk?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/125162/can-i-get-a-visitor-visa-invitation-from-a-non-uk-student-living-in-the-uk) the invitation letter will carry little weight with UKVI if your own personal circumstances are not strong (eg ties to your home country such as a job, and funds available to you for the visit). Reading [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) may help you prepare your application